# Add an extra line to addresses in Contacts in iOS?

Tags: contacts, ios

I need to add an address with more than 2 lines. Can I do it?

Comment: It's really a software limitation. I've tried writing the multiple lines address in Notes app and then past the text into the Address field on Contacts. But it just doesn't allow it to have more than one line.. Your best solution would be, as said by @Marc_Alx to edit the card on a computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you need to do a shift+enter (also called 'soft return') to do it (because 'enter' acts like 'tab'), you can't on iOS. According to this [recent post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189790/soft-return-character-shift-enter-on-ios) Zoagli points it in [his answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/189792/139286) you can't do it on iOS.

Alternatively you can try to add the soft return on a computer via Contact.app (on a mac), or via the web interface of your contact manager (Google contacts…)

PS iCloud on the web doesn't support soft return.

Answer (score 0):

Since is isn't something I know how to do on iOS, you'll need a computer (and contact syncing set up) or a Bluetooth keyboard connected to iOS.

From there, use Enter/Return to add more lines

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention that I am using iOS on an iPhone. I have updated the title.

Comment: I can't get iOS to do it ...should be shift/return but doesn't work in contacts - even Siri ignores the 'new line' command. On the mac, it's simple & synchronises straight to the phone.